# Angular Material Stepper and Step separados en diferentes componentes

Tags: angular, component, material

Me gustaría separar los steps del stepper, ya que no sabría cuantos steps se pueden generar en cada página (puede variar)

Page:

```
<test-stepper>
  <test-step></test-step>
  <test-step></test-step>
</test-stepper>
```

Stepper:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
  <ng-content select="test-step"></ng-content>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Step:

```
<mat-step>
  <ng-template matStepLabel>Label</ng-template>

  <div>
    <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
  </div>

</mat-step>
```

He realizado lo anterior, sin embargo no me pinta ningún step (he añadido en el provider del step el stepper). Pude conseguir algo con el cdk-step, pero me gusta el estilo de material para el stepper.

GRACIAS!! :D

Comment: Hi, this is StackOverflo in **spanish** , please translate your question or go to StackOverflow. Hola traduce tu pregunta ya que esto es StackOverflow en **español** o redirige tu pregunta a StackOverflow

Comment: Vale, me he equivocado al publicarlo, podría moverlo a la comunidad global?

Comment: Simplemente copia la pregunta de nuevo en [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Tambien podrías traducirla aqui y tal vez doblarías las probabilidades de recibir una respuesta.

Comment: Listo, gracias!! Lo he traducido aquí y tengo que esperar 90min para ponerlo allí jeje